# What's wrong with the cube projection?

Tags: texturing

I had to use it for the first time (using UV's for more than a year). Well, I messed it up. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried to rotate the coordinates of object's texture space and box mapping stopped working, that's because of how the box mapping works. It uses normals and when you rotate the object's texture space, the normals remain in the same orientation. To solve that you need to do box mapping with nodes instead of the function that comes with the Image node because it cannot take normal orientation into account when you rotate object's texture space. I have discussed this with someone on Blenderartists.org forums some time ago and came up with this to solve the issue:

[image: procedural box mapping]

You might want to put all those nodes into a group probably.

Here is the .blend file to play around:

[image]